# nodejs - writing strings to socket takes much time

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I heard that "Writing strings to socket takes more time in nodejs because core modules does not allow copying data directly to the socket but it requires intermediate copy in memory before going to socket". I heard this line saying by `Ryan Dahl` himself in an interview. I will post the link once it is found.

please correct me if I am wrong in understanding any of these, thanks.

My question is - can we skip this intermediate copying issue by modifying any code in core modules of the node ? I have experienced 5-6 seconds lag in my server when it copies bulky/large/huge strings to 150+ sockets.

I am trying to minimize the amount of data to broadcst but still on the other hand can we optimize this copying of strings to socket ?

As per the comment, adding more contents.

Example of what I am doing -

I am broadcasting leaderboard of n(>100) users[all these are in one room]. It is in JSON format. "leaderboard" is an array of players. Every object of player contains name,email,profile_pic_url,score,rank.
All objects are in json format.
user information is fetched from redis, and then rank is calculated. Then this leaderboard is broadcasted in the room.

Above operation happens every 2 seconds. So after first successful broadcast, I can see a lag.

adding the code - I am using

1. `socket.io` for accepting the connections
2. `redis store`
3. `room` feature of socket.io

code -

`io.sockets.in(RoomID).emit(StateName, LeaderboardObject);`

Comment: Your question is very vague.  I suggest you provide a reproducible example of the problem you're seeing.  I'm able to flush ~1MB buffers to thousands of clients without the difficulty you're seeing.  Perhaps your problem is that you're dealing with strings in some way.

Comment: thanks for the reply, question is now edited. code example is not given because it is emitting in the room in normal way.

Comment: "emitting in the room in normal way" that statement is meaningless.  Furthermore, it sounds to me like you're actually using Socket.IO or something similar, which has really nothing to do with TCP sockets at all (other than that they are used at an underlying layer)...  Clarify your question with code.

Comment: thanks, question updated.

Comment: my only main question is, can we modify core modules in nodejs in such a way that, it will copy stings directly to socket instead of intermediate copy.

Answer (score 0):

> can we skip this intermediate copying issue by modifying any code in core modules of the node ?

**No.**

You're using Socket.IO where the bulk of the work happens in JavaScript, not in a compiled extension.  Even if you did find a way to get around the buffer copying, you wouldn't be able to use it in this case.

I suggest posting a separate question, asking about the actual speed problem you are having and ways to optimize your code.

Comment: thanks, added [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779944/optimization-required-in-nodejs-code)

Comment: Note that for networking, it shouldn't really matter. Sending the data is always going to be slower than copying it anyway.

Comment: @Darkhogg If you're sending identical data to all of your clients, you can share some buffers... in theory anyway.  This doesn't work in Node.js since when you call `.write()`, a copy is made.  Plus, there are plenty of cases where I'd rather be spending my CPU cycles and memory on other tasks than dealing with buffers being copied for the network.